# Parallax site in Chrome and Safari makes images disappear at top

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, scroll, parallax

I am making a test making a Parallax website for future projects and am having trouble with the images in Chrome and Safari.

In Firefox the images scroll up past the top of the site but when scrolling with Chrome and Safari the images instantly disappear when they touch the top of the browser.

In my test, the yellow and brown slide both have images in them (Slide 1 and 5).

http://antonybearpark.co.uk/Parallax/

Comment: I don't see any browser issues, including Chrome or Safari, for your test link on a Windows XP machine. The yellow slide images are white triangle shapes as opposed to photographs in all browsers. I recommend testing your site using another PC.